Microsoft Visio Fit to Shape
I am trying to paste an screenshot of a video of a \ shaped object in Microsoft Visio and then change the borders of the image so that they are around the object. This way it is easier to add callouts to the right part of the object. If have tried many things, but I can't get it to work. Can anyone help me out?

@Gantendo Hi, the problem is that the object is company property, so I can't share it. The main goal of me is to be able to attach callouts easily to the object itself and not the rectangle it resides in.

Can you mock/simulate the issue with another image/video?

Add a connection point to the shape at the appropriate coordinates and then glue the callout to that connection point.
